# Comparing two files for duplicate strings using mac bash

Tags: macos, bash, loops, while-loop

I am trying to go through two .txt files to find matches and only print unique lines. I have a list of numbers and names and a second list of only partial numbers.

The file formats are like this
5553239090,batman

second file is only six numbers
555323

I want to make sure that I am only taking out the lines that match the first six numbers so if I had 239090 I would not want that to take out the line. So far what I have found that works is this

```
while read line

do
echo $line
    while read line2

        do

            if [[ "${line:0:6}" != "$line2" ]]; then

                echo $line >> uniqueList2.txt
                echo ${line:0:6}
            fi

        done < file2.txt

done < file1.txt
```

for some reason though it is not taking out all of the matches only some of them. It seems like the it matches the numbers at the top of file2 the best and the further down the list the are the more likely it is to miss it.

Is there something I missed or a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1];next} {for (i in a) if (index($0, i)==1) print}' file2 file1
```

OR else you can use this `grep`

```
grep -f <(sed 's/^/\^/' file1) file2
```

Comment: I tried that but the problem was that I was getting matches from anywhere in the number not just in the first 6

Comment: It is finding some of the matches but not all of them. I have a list of 50 numbers with names and of those 50 I should be matching 25 of them. With my original code I was pulling out 3-5 depending on the order of the list and with the AWK I am pulling out 8 matches. I am not sure why it is not working.

Comment: If you provide some more sample if input data that is not matching I can look into it.

Comment: Just started using SO how can I link files on here?

Comment: You can't link files here. Provide your files on pastebin.com and provide link here

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Vmycg7gt this is file1.   http://pastebin.com/VDM72eRP this is file 2.   I didnt put up all of file2 because its 37,000 entries.

Comment: See updated answer, even this `grep` is also giving me 22 matches in output.

Comment: I am still only getting 8 matches with both grep and awk. I switched to the same list that I posted and I am still getting the same result. I am not sure what I am doing differently that I am getting less results.

Comment: Last comment before i signoff.. Using cat -vte make sure there is no special character in your files.

Comment: Could it be that not all carriage returns are what you think? What was the origin of these files? If the code says there is no match, maybe there is no match...

Comment: I would suggest doing `head file1 | cat -vte` and `head file2 | cat -vte` to see you get normal carriage returns as end of line and there is nothing before numbers at start of line.

Comment: doing that I am only getting returns on the first nine lines of each file. I double checked and there are no spaces or characters in front of the lines or after them.

Comment: What do you mean by `I am only getting returns on the first nine lines of each file`? Just heck with `cat -vte file1` OR `cat -vte file2`

Comment: ok when I do that each line ends with a $ is that the way it should be? Sorry I just started learning this stuff and there is still a lot I am not familiar with.

Comment: Unless you provide me any new information I cannot suggest any new trick. I have tested both the command of my answer with your 2 input files are both work fine on OSX.

Comment: Ok my issue was that I was adding textEdit and it was adding some formatting nonsense that was giving me issue. I switched to sublime and now everything is working the way that it should be. Thank you for all your help, I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Hmm that's why I use `MaxVim` on my OSX :) Glad it worked out for you.